# How can I best manage Transact-SQL scripts with Git and SSMS (including add-ons and running two tool separately)

Tags: git, sql-server, sql-server-management-studio

At one point in time my team managed our library of Transact-SQL scripts with TFS from within SSMS, which used the "traditional" Microsoft Solution / Project structure for storing scripts. It worked fine. Later, the source control packages in SSMS were turned off by default but could be made available.

Now I want to use git (GitHub) to maintain a Transact-SQL script library, but haven't been able to find a tool to do so. There may still be add-ons that version the database objects within the add-ons, but here I am looking to manage a library of Transact-SQL scripts. I do not want the tool to create or modify any database objects itself.

If there is no tool or add-on for Git (GitHub) and SSMS, maybe we could manage the script library from Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code or Azure Data Studio?

I'm looking for recommendations for what combinations of tools and settings would work most smoothly, with a strong preference for doing the actual script editing in SSMS. If necessary, I can edit files in SSMS and do the source control from a separate tool such as SourceTree.

As I am new to this "Software Recommendations" site, I couldn't add SSMS or sql-server-management-studio as tags

Answer (score 0):

Team Foundation Server [rebranded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/tfs-is-now-azure-devops-server?view=azure-devops) to Azure DevOps Server.

You can now choose between:

- Azure DevOps Service: which is the cloud version
- Azure DevOps Server: which is the on-prem version

Azure DevOps is standard Git.
You can use Visual Studio or VS Code with third-party Git services.